# Extract data points of figure file in MAT LAB

Tags: plot, matlab-figure

I have imported a shape file and save it as a MAT LAB figure file. I need to extract data points along the boundary of the figure file as (x,y) coordinates. can someone help me with this!

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your figure (2D image, 3D image , chart ,...).
You can read a fig files by this command

```
>> figFile = load('1.fig','-mat')

figFile = 

    hgS_070000: [1x1 struct]

after that you can find all data in this structure by using dot

>> figFile.hgS_070000

ans = 

          type: 'figure'
        handle: 1
    properties: [1x1 struct]
      children: [1x1 struct]
       special: []

>> figFile.hgS_070000.children
ans = 
          type: 'axes'
        handle: 176.08251953125
    properties: [1x1 struct]
      children: [1x1 struct]
       special: [4x1 double]

>> figFile.hgS_070000.children.children
ans = 
          type: 'graph2d.lineseries'
        handle: 177.0830078125
    properties: [1x1 struct]
      children: []
       special: []

>> figFile.hgS_070000.children.children.properties
ans = 
              Color: [0 0 1]
              XData: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
              YData: [2 1 5 6 4 8 8 4 8]
    ApplicationData: [1x1 struct]
                .
                .
                .
```

Ploted data can be extracted by this

```
>> Y = figFile.hgS_070000.children.children.properties.YData
>> X = figFile.hgS_070000.children.children.properties.XData
```

Comment: Thank you! I got the points as X,Y coordinates that makes a polygon, I appreciate further need to get the intersection points with the polygon and the circle with a given radius, since i have only some points in the polygon how can I able to take those intersection points?